# Rails : Could not locate Gemfile

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, gemfile

```
/Users/mac/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3@global/gems/bundler-1.7.4/lib/bundler/shared_helpers.rb:24:in `default_gemfile': Could not locate Gemfile (Bundler::GemfileNotFound)
    from /Users/mac/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3@global/gems/bundler-1.7.4/lib/bundler/shared_helpers.rb:29:in `default_lockfile'
    from /Users/mac/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.1.3@global/gems/bundler-1.7.4/lib/bundler.rb:253:in `default_lockfile'
    from /Users/mac/bin/spring:10:in `<top (required)>'
    from bin/rails:3:in `load'
    from bin/rails:3:in `<main>'
```

hi,

when i try to run 'rails new myproject' or 'rails -v' i have this message but rails is installed. i don't understand. Someone can help me.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Do you have a `Gemfile` in the current working directory?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's either not in the proper path or it isn't installed. Do this `gem install bundler` also if you are running `rails -v` you should get a version like this:

```
rails -v
Rails 4.2.0.beta2
```

If you don't, then that means rails is not installed either. Run `gem install rails`

Here is information of setting up rails: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html

Answer (score 4):

I had the exact problem.

As it turned out, the problem was I had a hidden `./bin` directory.
When I run `rails new myapp`, it's using binaries in the bin folder. In my case it was `./bin/spring` specifically.

I removed this `./bin` directory and all is well now.